# Graphical simulation matlab cellular automata

Tags: matlab, animation, imshow

I would like to implement the kind of graphic simulation shown in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pi256PoyNsg. I have seen that with the function imshow() properly placed in a loop, you can make animations of two colors of this type. However, I would like to be able to add more colors. What are my options?

This is an example of what I would do to do a binary animation with imshow(). Every step the matrix A is initialized at random.

```
N=100; %Size of matrix
A=rand(N,N); %Matrix with random values between 0 and 1
imshow(A) %Print image
for j=1:1000
   A=rand(N,N); % A is rewritten
   imshow(A) % Reprint matrix 
   pause(0.005) % Wait 
end
```

Comment: Your question looks quite straightforward, but in order to help we need a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I use a pre-defined RGB color palatte of size `Mx3` where `M` is the total number of colors you want to draw with.

`imshow()` supports RGB image input as a `NxNx3` matrix.

Sample code:

```
clear;clc;close all

% C is a M-by-3 matrix representing M RGB colors. 
C = [1 1 0;1 0 1;0 1 1];
M = size(C,1);

N=100; %Size of matrix
A=rand(N,N); %Matrix with random values between 0 and 1
imshow(A) %Print image
B = zeros(N,N,3);
for j=1:10
   A=randi(M,N,N); % A is rewritten
   B(:,:,1) = arrayfun(@(ind) C(ind,1), A);
   B(:,:,2) = arrayfun(@(ind) C(ind,2), A);
   B(:,:,3) = arrayfun(@(ind) C(ind,3), A);
   imshow(B) % Reprint matrix 
   pause(0.005) % Wait 
end
```